# I can connect to DB through Sequel Pro, but not through command line

Tags: mysql, database, ssh, sequelpro

I can connect to my db with Sequel Pro just fine, but I can't through the command line. I've followed their instructions here: http://www.sequelpro.com/docs/Connecting_to_a_MySQL_Server_on_a_Remote_Host#Do_I_need_to_use_the_Terminal_for_SSH_connections.3F

In their command I substitute the following from the connection window and SSH tab in Sequel Pro:

```
ssh -L 1234:mysqlhost:3306 sshuser@sshhost

mysqlhost => MySQL Host
sshuser => SSH User
sshhost => SSH Host
```

And when prompted for a password, I use the one from "SSH Password"

I'm not sure what Sequel Pro is doing differently behind the scenes.

Comment: So, you run that command, and *then* what happens, or what else do you do? You're just setting up a tunnel with that SSH command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That instruction from the Sequel Pro docs isn't quite the whole story; it's just telling you how to set up a tunnel. You need a second step to actually *use* it to connect to a MySQL server.

The actual process is two steps:

1. Create the tunnel.

   ```
   ssh -N -L 1234:mysqlhost:3306 sshuser@sshhost
   ```

   The `-N` that I added just tells `ssh` that you're *only* setting up a tunnel and you don't want to start a shell on `sshhost`. Running this command will look like it does nothing: that's what it should look like.

   As long as the `ssh` command is running, connections to port 1234 on your local machine will be tunneled through `sshhost` to port 3306 (the MySQL port) on `mysqlhost`.
2. Connect to MySQL using the tunnel.

   You now need to run the `mysql` command line client. The `ssh` command you just ran is still running, so the easiest thing for you to do is open a new Terminal window or tab, and run:

   ```
   mysql -P 1234 -u mysqluser -p
   ```

   to connect to your database. The `-P 1234` part is the only out-of-the-ordinary part of this command, and it just makes the `mysql` client connect using the port you set up in the first command to do the tunneling.

When you're done with the tunnel, either close the original Terminal window or use <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> to stop the `ssh` process.

Comment: How could this be used for creating a database on the server in a bash script? Would be awesome if you would check out my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905077/create-mysql-database-through-ssh-in-a-bash-script

Comment: This worked for me almost exactly but in step 2 I had to specify that the host was 127.0.0.1 like `mysql -u user -h 127.0.0.1 -p` otherwise it wouldn't work.