# Create mySQL database through ssh in a bash script

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, unix, ssh

I want to create a database on a remote server through ssh with a bash script. Something like this

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh user@example.com 'mysql -h example.com -uroot -pMYPASSWD -e "CREATE DATABASE $1;"'
```

So that I in terminal can run it like

```
$ myBashScript nameOfNewDatabase
```

Comment: Try this: ssh user@example.com "mysqladmin create $1"

Comment: http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/mysqladmin/ gives details of options, e.g. --user=root --password=MYPASSWD etc.

Comment: Got error bash: mysqladmin: command not found, got the same when I tried the one I wrote in desc, but mysql is installed. I'll check if mysqladmin is installed.

Comment: Mysqladmin is installed, but when I try to run the command remotely with ssh user@example.com "mysqladmin create $1" it gives me the error above.

Comment: Be aware that "mysqladmin" is not the local one, it's the one installed on the server. Try something like  ssh user@example.com "/path/to/mysqladmin create $1" and forget about relying on your remote PATH settings ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following script can remotely execute arbitrary commands

```
#!/bin/bash
# call mysql on a remote server to execute the given command 

# show usage and exit
usage() {
  echo "$0 server sql-command"  1>&2
    exit 1
}

# check number of arguments
if [ $# -lt 2 ]
then
  usage
fi

# get server name and sql command
server="$1"
sql="$2"

# copy command to a temporary file
tmpsql="/tmp/sql$$"
echo "$sql" > $tmpsql

# copy command file to server
scp $tmpsql $server:$tmpsql
# run command remotely with removing command file afterwards
ssh $server "mysql -uroot -pPASSWORD < $tmpsql;rm $tmpsql"
# remove local copy of command file
rm $tmpsql
```

Comment: Awesome! So, it scp's a script file to the server, then executes it? I'll check it out later today.

Comment: It throws me: `bash: mysql: command not found`

Is there some setting I'm missing on the server?

Comment: you need to make sure the PATH is set in the ssh session or specify the fully qualifying name of mysql in the script. Use "which mysql" in a ssh terminal session to find it e.g.
>which mysql
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql

Comment: So it does not help that the PATH is set in the bash profile on the server, I have to somehow declare it in this script as well? How would that be done?

Comment: with macports I have to put the PATH declaration in .ssh/environment e.g.

    PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/local/bin

Comment: Ok, I got so far that I can run mysql commands, had to write the whole path to mysql. But now it tells me -e needs an argument. Got any clue?

Comment: my script was not using -e put piping the commands into mysql. I purposely tried to avoid the issue of escaping the quotes need for -e. Over an ssh connection escaping quotes and other characters needing to be escaped can get tricky.

Comment: ah, sorry man. Your so right. This is totally perfect! Thank you so much for your help! This has been a big issue for me.